# regarding computing output size for convolutional layer

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am following up the lecture notes posted on http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/   I am sort of confusing about one example given in the notes.  It says `input size w=5` I don't know where does this `w=5` come from?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the figure, the original input is a vector containing 5 elements: [1, 2, -1, 1, -3]. The input is then zero padded, so that convolving it with the filter ([1, 0, -1]) will produce an output of a particular size. During the convolution, the filter can't slide past the end of the input; its furthest offsets are where the edge of the filter aligns with the edge of the input. Looking at the left panel of the figure, if there were no zero padding, the output of the convolution would contain only 3 elements.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that it comes from padding.